After logout I can't access the login
The problem is this:

I have a Myaccount activity which has a logout button which when clicked will delete all the shared preferences and redirect to splash activity.java

In splash there is a clause of email id of the registered user is found via firebase auth then redirect to home activity otherwise onboarding.

So after getting through onboarding i reach the email activity where there is a button named as "continue Google" button which was designed in such a way to register a user and send data to server or in case of login retrieve the email id from server and log in the user.


Well after the logout and redirection to splash, onboarding and finally to Email the continue Google button doesn't work when I click on it.
Last time when I put this in chatgpt he had done a thing then after logout when I get redirected and click on continue Google button it will automatically fetch the user data and logs me in.
So please help

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
